# Search engine for website

Tags: php, search-engine

I am thinking of having a search engine for my website. However, I came to know about using PHP to browse through a number of indexes saved in our database. Is it a right method or any other algorithm for doing the same thing is available..

Please do tell me any other possible way of implementing a search engine for my own website.

For your information, my website is an informative one with just HTML contents.
Thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: Depends, how big is your database? Many Rows/Much data?

Comment: `searchrequest site:yoursite.com` @ google.com ;)

Comment: @eddie there are lots of data  infact its about 70 pages for now.. It will further increase in future

Comment: PHP is not an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try mysql full text search or for more no of records i would suggest sphinx.

You could use Sphinx for this kind of search (and it would surely be very fast), but the kind of fields you want to search on are really better served directly within the database - making some assumptions that you're providing good indexes on the tables.

The real strength of Sphinx lies in full-text search, which you don't indicate you'll need. Click here for more details http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads .

Answer (score 2):

`Google Custom Search engine` will be the perfect solution for you

http://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement search on your site, from a embedded Google Search, using a simple 'Like "%xyz%"' or 'match against' type query in Mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Or using a more powerful solution like Apache Lucene and Solr.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Which solution you would use depends on factors too numerous to go into here - including but not limited to your own available time, resources and technical ability.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to re-invent the wheel and write something from scratch, I'd recommend using an existing product unless you have some very specific need.

I've used [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) in the past; it was a bit of a pain to get running but it works well for a general-purpose search.